# Maximum likelihood and autocorrelation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, panel-data, autocorrelation, inference, clustered-standard-errors

We have panel data and we want to estimate the following linear model:

$Y_{it}=βX_{it}+\alpha_{i}+\epsilon_{it}$

Suppose that, for some reason, we must estimate this model by the maximum likelihood random effects estimator. In addition, suppose that we have autocorrelation in the disturbances.

Do we need to explicitly model the autocorrelation in the maximum likelihood function or we can simply estimate clustered standard errors?